# detect yellow color in opencv

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, computer-vision

i convert image to HSV after it i make the threshold the yellow color so the code is 
     cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(112, 100, 100), cvScalar(124, 255, 255), imgThreshed); 
but it doesn't work always give me black image .

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You should try this tutorial for ["tracking yellow objects".](http://aishack.in/tutorials/tracking-colored-objects-opencv/)

It gives a HSV range of `cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(20, 100, 100), cvScalar(30, 255, 255), imgThreshed)` for yellow object.

If you have any doubt on selecting color, try this : http://www.yafla.com/yaflaColor/ColorRGBHSL.aspx

Comment: but if we have a condition like we have cyan 23 , and green yellow as values like 40 , 69 than how the website you mention work to find their HSV

Comment: You need color values in RGB or HSV or CMYK or any standard color space. Then you can convert them to other color space. Just google for the conversion formula (or any site that does the conversion for you). Normally, cyan, magenta and yellow are counted together. Never heard saying in terms of Cyan, Green and Yellow.

Comment: You can see here , I am trying to do this , in which i have to deal with all these or may be i am interpreting wrong ,`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23312898/trying-to-make-color-balance-of-photoshop-using-opencv?noredirect=1#comment35693629_23312898` here is my situation

Answer (score 6):

I know  question you ask is for c++, I have python script to detect yellow color which may help you or somebody else..

```
def colorDetection(image):
    hsv = cv2.cvtColor(image,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)

    '''Red'''
    # Range for lower red
    red_lower = np.array([0,120,70])
    red_upper = np.array([10,255,255])
    mask_red1 = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)

    # Range for upper range
    red_lower = np.array([170,120,70])
    red_upper = np.array([180,255,255])
    mask_red2 = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)

    mask_red = mask_red1 + mask_red2

    red_output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask_red)

    red_ratio=(cv2.countNonZero(mask_red))/(image.size/3)

    print("Red in image", np.round(red_ratio*100, 2))



    '''yellow'''
    # Range for upper range
    yellow_lower = np.array([20, 100, 100])
    yellow_upper = np.array([30, 255, 255])
    mask_yellow = cv2.inRange(hsv, yellow_lower, yellow_upper)

    yellow_output = cv2.bitwise_and(image, image, mask=mask_yellow)

    yellow_ratio =(cv2.countNonZero(mask_yellow))/(image.size/3)

    print("Yellow in image", np.round(yellow_ratio*100, 2))
```

Comment: red_ratio=(cv2.countNonZero(mask_red))/(image.size/3) 

Why did you divide here by 3??

Answer (score 2):

you can also convert RGB into HUE

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hue

in the link you have the formula, then you know that yellow has a HUE value around 60.

Comment: In OpenCV HUE values are between 0-180, so values around **30** is ok.

Answer (score 2):

for yellow color the range as should be from 23 to 40 for example as per i am using in my yellow object tracking program

//Thresholding the frame for yellow

```
   cvInRangeS(hsvframe,cvScalar(23,41,133),cvScalar(40,150,255),threshy);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your hue values may be incorrect. I'm not sure where you're getting the 112-124 hue range from if you're trying to detect yellow. I would expect the values to be closer to 40, so maybe try a range like 34-46.

Comment: it's right thank u 
so could u write ranges for each color (red , green , blue ) please ?? ???

Comment: The problem with RGB space is that "colours" don't have as simple an interpretation for what we perceive as a constant colour. I would recommend you run a tool like Paint and pick out low and high RGB ranges that you feel are appropriate for your task and use those values if you want to run on an RGB image as opposed to an HSV image. You can start with a value like `(255,255,0)` and see where that gets you if you're looking for yellow. Note also that OpenCV stores things in BGR order, so `(0,255,255)` may be representative of the range that you plug in to `inRange()`.

Comment: cvInRangeS(imgHSV, cvScalar(0, 0, 60), cvScalar(0, 0, 255), imgThreshed);
it doesn't detect red color !!!
may be the range is not right 
can u give me example on another color to know how to conclude the right range for the other colors