# Trying to make color balance of photoshop using opencv

Tags: image, opencv, image-processing, colors, computer-vision

I want to make the same thing programmatically like `Color balance` in `Photoshop` , like in below image

[image]

if we have same bar positions in Photoshop then how we can make them in OpenCV , because the problem which I am not understanding is that we have the image with `RGB` format yes we can convert in other color format but how I can understand these values (do we need to subtract the Cyan values in OpenCV if Cyan Level is -20 in PS ? Or we need to Add ?) and did the same operation in OpenCV ,
For example if I need to change values in `Cyan` , `Magenta` and `Blue` Do I need to convert image first to add values in Cyan and magenta and then convert it back to `BGR` and then increase `blue` ?
And is there any built in function in OpenCv for `Shadows , MidTones and Highlight`

I am trying something like this

```
Mat img = imread("E:\\raw_3.jpg");
vector<Mat> colors;
split(img,colors);
colors[0] += 69;
colors[1] += 40 ;
colors[2] -= 23 ;
merge(colors,img);
imshow("image" , img);
imwrite("E:\\color_balance.jpg",img);
waitKey();
```

for Cyan - red = -23 Magenta - Green = 40 Yellow - Blue = 69 But i am not getting the accurate result as it should be

Comment: i'm not familiar with photoshop, but you can do it by mapping the pixel intensity values of a channel using a function, Iout(x,y) = f(Iin(x,y)), where Iout(x,y) is the new intensity of pixel at (x,y). the function could be a simple liner function, a piecewise function, a spline etc. in opencv, you can map the pixel values using a lookup table.

Answer (score 2):

1, Try it - all you have to do is change the sign, and recompile!

2, Learn about other [color representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV) - you almost never want to do this sort of operation directly in RGB.

Color is surprisingly complex, a good place to start is the [color faq](http://www.poynton.com/ColorFAQ.html)

Comment: You mean to say that convert my color space it `Cyan magenta and yellow` and then i need to something like `Cyan+20` , `Magentta+30` and `Yellow-25` ?

Comment: Convert to HSL/HSV and change the Hue then convert back. The cyan+20 isn't adding 20 to cyan as such it's just an arbitrary amount of change in the hue toward cyan or magenta.

Comment: thank you , but if we check colors on PS and then use their values in opncv they are not giving the same result , this is due to using wrong appraoch or values differ ?

Comment: when we split image we come with 3 color component , how i can deal only wit hue while i want to change the color of cyan magenta and yellow , lets suppose i change the hue towards cyan then how can i change the same hue towards magenta it may changes the value of cyan